# Hamburger Menu in Windows/Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, win-universal-app, windows-8.1-universal

Is it posible to implement an Hamburger menu (or similar) in Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's an Hamburger menu?

Comment: I'd use the Bottom App Bar instead. That allows up to four buttons and five menu items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A really quick search brings up results like this one:

[github.com/FrayxRulez/SplitView](https://github.com/FrayxRulez/SplitView)

> This repository contains a porting of SplitView control available in
>   Windows 10 for Runtime 8.1 and Silverlight 8.X
>
> Properties are the same, so if in future you want to port your app to
>   10 you have just to remove the Universal.UI.Xaml.Controls namespace.

Comment: Thank you. I can assure you that if I had found a solution, I wouldn't have posted

Answer (score 3):

Windows 8.1 doesn't support Splitview which is mostly used to create a hamburger menu. You can however code it all, but that will be a big mess. I Suggest you take a look at UWP and the controls inside  UWP, to easily create a hamburger menu. There is many tutorials on how to create one in UWP.